# Differential Equation with sketching graph

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation:

$$
y' = \frac{x\left(x^2+1\right)}{4y^3},\,\,y(0) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tag{1}
$$

a) Find explicit solution and determine the interval in which the solution is defined.
b) Sketch a rough graph of the solution.

I tried:

$$
\int 4y^3dy = \int x^3+x dx.\tag{2}
$$
Eq.(2) has a solution of the form,
$$
y^4 = \frac{1}{4}x^4+\frac{1}{2}x^2+C.
$$

What am I suppose to do next?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the RHS is $\frac 14(x^2+1)^2$, (using the contour condition) so this is really $2y^2=x^2+1$. What does this look like to you?

Comment: Again make it like separate equation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I dont know what to do after 2y^2=x^2+1. Help pls

Comment: A hint is that it is a conic section. It is not hard, you can look some information at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section).

Comment: Ok, I see. But I should draw it only in part b)

Comment: In the first part I need to solde DE equation

Comment: You've got $y(x)^4=\frac 14 x^4 + \frac 12 x^2 + C$ for some constant $C$, right? Plug in $x=0$ and use the initial condition $y(0)=-1/\sqrt 2$ to find the desired constant $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is referring to field lines. The solution might act differently depending on your initial values and it is possible that you are being asked to describe this using a graph. This would be a good resource if so http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DirectionFields.aspx. For the solution take the integral of both sides and then solve for y, this will be your solution.

Comment: Graph is ok, but how to solve this equation?

Comment: You have already solved it when you integrated it. Now evaluate the constant C for a few cases of (x,y).